# Store credentials in Powershell session

Tags: powershell, session

I use a script frequently in which the requirement is to use alternate credentials for invoking commands on a remote server. The challenge is I have to enter the Credentials everytime I run the script.

Is there a way to store the credentials in the current active powershell session? For instance, when executing the script for the first time it should ask for the credentials and subsequent runs of the script should not ask for the credentials.

I have come up with this code in my script but does not work as expected when I am passing the $cred variable to the -Credential parameter.

```
    New-Variable -Name Env -Value @{} -Scope GLOBAL -Force

    If (Test-Path Variable::global:Env)
    {
        $cred = $global:Env
    }
    Else
    {
        New-Variable -Name Env -Value @{} -Scope GLOBAL -Force
        $cred = $global:Env.(Get-Credential) | Out-Null
    }
```

Can you please help in pointing out where I am going wrong here?

Thank you!!

Comment: @PetSerAl, I tried that as well in my script but I still keep getting the credential prompt everytime the script is executed. I think this is because (Get-Credential) is called when the script is executed everytime.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have edited my original question. Could you please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store `PSCredential` object in global variable. You first check if variable exists and contains `PSCredential` object. If not, than you as for credential from user:

```
if(!(Test-Path Variable::global:GlobalCred)-or($global:GlobalCred-isnot[pscredential])){
    $global:GlobalCred=Get-Credential
}
$Cred=$global:GlobalCred
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly in my script. Marked your answer.

Comment: Q: why store it in a global variable ? I could use `$mycr=get-credential`